# Good ways to create step by step creation process in google app engine with django forms

Tags: django, google-app-engine, templates

I'm using AppEngine and django forms passing template_values and using base.html with {% extends "base.html" %} this works well in a testing environment when I have one big form for adding entities.

I'm good in python, good with the datastore, but my html is weak/OLD

I want to have a step by step process for creating datastore entities.  In broad strokes, what are some common methods/search-terms I should be using?  I've heard that I might be hitting a bit of a limit at some point by using django instead of some other framework - am I already at that point?...can't be?...

Comment: What do you mean by a step-by-step process for creating datastore entities? I guess you mean something else that can already be done in the admin console, but please be a bit more specific.

Comment: When people visit my app engine site they will want to create a record - so for instance say it was a real-estate site, I want to guide them through creating data store records so on the first page 'please enter address and property descriptions', next page, 'please upload pictures', next page, 'links to associate with property', next page 'verify all that', publish.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for Django Form Wizard?
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/